# ¿Cómo puedo configurar un botón para cerrar un aviso que sale arriba de una página web?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

Tengo una duda con respecto a lo siguiente:

Estoy creando un aviso para mostrarlo en la parte de arriba de mi web, de manera que todos lo vean y estén informados de las novedades del mismo. Hasta ahorita, todo bien; no obstante, quisiera saber cómo puedo configurar un botón que permita cerrar ese aviso, de manera tal que ya no vuelva a aparecer a lo largo de la navegación.

La siguiente imagen es un avance del aviso. La figura con la X que aparece dentro del aviso es el botón que quiero configurar para que funcione como una función que sólo responda a esa parte de la página web y cierre el aviso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Por favor sube tu estructura html, el código que has intentado, una imagen no nos sirve para ayudarte, es importante que leas [ask], saludos !

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ocupar `localStorage` puedes leer sobre el [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) si lo deseas.

En fin de tal modo que si la variable `localStorage` existe no mostrar el aviso de lo contrario se entiende que el usuario entra a tu web por primera vez.

*Te dejo un ejemplo rápido:*

```
localStorage.setItem('mensaje', false);


if(localStorage.getItem('mensaje') == true){
  document.getElementById('mensaje').remove()
}


document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('mensaje', true);

  document.getElementById('mensaje').remove()
})
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo puedo ampliar la función de LocalStorage en mi aviso, de manera tal que cada vez que el usuario entre por mi web y vea las páginas disponibles no se tenga que topar varias veces con los avisos? Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

A su `button` le puede asignar un `evento` `onclick="myfunction()"`que lo lleve a la `function` para quitar el elemento del `DOM`

Y la `function` para remover el elemento puede ser:

```
function myfunction(){
  document.getElementById("idPestaña").remove;
}
```